# Compare and loop every row of in between time in a second dataframe, if match copy values from columns of the same row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have two DFs:

- DF1 has a column for time

```
MsgTime 
13:45:33
14:13:25
15:16:43
16:51:19
```

- DF2 has two columns of time, and additional two columns of information

```
MsgTime1 | MgsTime2 | Temperature | Humidity
13:40:33   13:50:13    21           45
14:16:43   14:26:43    22           56
16:49:11   16:59:02    32           40
```

So if `MsgTime` is in between `MsgTime1` and `MsgTime2` from DF2, copy the `Temperature` and `Humidity` to DF1 as output. The loop should compare every row to find a match, if not leave it blank. A desired output should look like this:

```
MgsTime | Temperature | Humidity
13:45:33   21            45
14:13:25   NaN           NaN
15:16:43   NaN           NaN
16:51:19    32           40
```

I tried to do like a double for loop, but it didn't seem to work:

```
for i, row in DF1.iterrows():
    for j, row2 in DF2.iterrows():
        if (row2['MsgTime1'] <= row['MsgTime']) and (row['MsgTime'] <=  row2['MsgTime2']):
            row['Temperature'] = row2['Temperature']
            row['Humidity'] = row2['Humidity']
        else:
            row2 += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A package [piso](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (pandas interval set operations), provides a very fast implementation for this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.to_datetime(["13:45:33", "14:13:25", "15:16:43", "16:51:19"]),
    columns=["MsgTime"],
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "MsgTime1": pd.to_datetime(["13:40:33", "14:16:43", "16:49:11"]),
        "MsgTime2": pd.to_datetime(["13:50:13", "14:26:43", "16:59:02"]),
        "Temperature":[21,22,32],
        "Humidity":[45,56,40],
    }
)
```

**solution**

Create a dataframe with `Temperature` and `Humidity` columns, indexed by a `pandas.IntervalIndex`

```
df3 = df2[["Temperature", "Humidity"]].set_index(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2["MsgTime1"], df2["MsgTime2"]))
```

`df3` looks like this

```
                                            Temperature  Humidity
(2021-11-03 13:40:33, 2021-11-03 13:50:13]           21        45
(2021-11-03 14:16:43, 2021-11-03 14:26:43]           22        56
(2021-11-03 16:49:11, 2021-11-03 16:59:02]           32        40
```

Note since no date component was provided it just assumes today's date.  You could alternatively use `pandas.Timedelta` instead of `pandas.Timestamp` - the approach will work the same

Next use [`piso.lookup`](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/piso.lookup.html#piso.lookup)

```
piso.lookup(df3, df1["MsgTime"])
```

which produces

```
                     Temperature  Humidity
2021-11-03 13:45:33         21.0      45.0
2021-11-03 14:13:25          NaN       NaN
2021-11-03 15:16:43          NaN       NaN
2021-11-03 16:51:19         32.0      40.0
```

**note**: I am the creator of piso. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.Interval` with `pandas.to_datetime`:

```
df2.index = df2[["MsgTime1", "MsgTime2"]].apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*pd.to_datetime(x)), axis=1)

s = pd.to_datetime(df["MsgTime"])
for k in ["Temperature", "Humidity"]:
    df[k] = s.map(df2[k])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    MsgTime  Temperature  Humidity
0  13:45:33         21.0      45.0
1  14:13:25          NaN       NaN
2  15:16:43          NaN       NaN
3  16:51:19         32.0      40.0
```

Comment: I get the error `ValueError: left side of interval must be <= right side` at the first line. I don't quite get it because the left hand side `MsgTime1` is always smaller than right hand side `MsgTime2`